# cannot resolve method 'putExtra(android.os.bundle)'

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

In a Fragment inside `onCreateView`

```
putExtra(dataBundle);
```

gives

> cannot resolve method 'putExtra(android.os.bundle)' error

but

```
putExtra("id", id_To_Search);
```

works fine. I want to send dataBunle guide me what i am missing.

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                int id_To_Search = position + 1;
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class).putExtra(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the error?  When you are putting a bundle in an intent or trying to get it?

Comment: @jasz cannot resolve method 'putExtra(android.os.bundle)'

Comment: you need to do it this way putExtra("id", id_To_Search);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is:

the method names is putExtras.... you are missing a **s**

Do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class).putExtras(dataBundle);
```

---

Another example:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

Comment: I want to send bundle with my intent. i know this works its in the question

Comment: you miss an s, the method name is putExtras, with s at the end, not put extra.... I updated my answer, give a try and please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

`putExtra()` do not return Intent instance. So try this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(dataBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

But You can send this integer as following...

**Sender Side:**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("id", id_To_Search);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**Receiver Side:**

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
```

Comment: Tried it Same issue persissts

Comment: you are doing things in wrong way... I mean, if you just want to pass an integer to another activity, then why are you using Bundle. you can pass integer directly with intent.